# Eclipse formatter and Double Brace Initialization

Tags: java, eclipse

Is it feasible to tune Eclipse formatter to format [Double Brace Initialization](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?DoubleBraceInitialization) nicely?

Thanks.

Comment: Nicely? Eclipse is formatting it , and I think it is nice.

Comment: @RakeshJuyal See the linked article - the two opening braces should be on the same line, and the two closing braces should too. I know of no way to tell the Eclipse formatter to do that. Also, how should the source look like when the class has content in addition to the initializer? The formatter would have to look until the end of the class to know the distinction.

Comment: @ChristianSemrau Got your point. :)

Comment: Did you find an answer ?

Answer (score 0):

This is not the actual answer but as I can't show you the formatted code in comment I am using this.

**Unformatted Code:**

```
new ArrayList<String>() {   {           add("RJ");              add("MJ");}};
```

**Formatted code** [ ECLIPSE Formatter ]

```
    new ArrayList<String>() {
        {
            add("RJ");
            add("MJ");
        }
    };
```

I somehow feel that it is **Nicely** formatted. Are you asking for something else ?